# Analyzing raw data from a Google Sheet into a 'dashboard'

Tags: google-sheets

Situation:

Every time I visit a member of my field team, I put their 'score' into a Google Form, which then puts the raw data into this [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lMSJA2LM7em3PDZM344QIr2SA8uRWDYYHnOFEacmbCA/edit?usp=sharing).

**I'd like a second Dashboard sheet that has:**

- all of the raw data, plus a calculation of their "overall score" (an average of parts A, B, C, and D)
- a way to easily see the average score of each person per quarter (Q4 2016, Q1 2017)
- a way to easily see the average score for each type of Observation (Live vs scenario #1, 2, 3)
- a drop-down where I can select a user and see their scores on a chart compared to the rest of the group's averages

I've done some of the work [[here]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lMSJA2LM7em3PDZM344QIr2SA8uRWDYYHnOFEacmbCA/edit#gid=501829031), but would love some help to figure out the best way to do this (keeping in mind of the performance of the sheet considering I'd actually have thousands of rows of raw data).

```
*Things to note:*  

* I might score one person twice in a row before getting to the next person

* I might score one person twice in a month (I'm not sure how to show that in the Dashboard)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.  I'm trying to learn as much as I can, but it's all still pretty new to me.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Either someone would need to do a lot of work to provide what you want, or have created something very similar.  You will need to narrow down what part of this you want to work on, try to get it to work, and if you have a specific problem, then consider posting.  Do you want to work with functions inside of cells?  Do you want to write code?

Comment: @SandyGood  OK. Well my first quest for guidance is around performance.  What would be the best way to keep the sheet from having to spend a ton of time loading the various calculations I'm after?  Functions in Row 2 that apply to each column below? Functions in each cell (a la drag down)? Pivot tables? Scripting?  I'm open to any of the above.  I've tried to get it to work with decent success but get stuck on how to get the dashboard to show each score broken down by both month  and type of observation.

Comment: Ask your question on the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs)